# How to set document quality while ingesting document into MarkLogic through PutMarkLogic NiFi processor?

Tags: apache-nifi, marklogic

I'm using `NiFi 1.21.0` and `nifi-marklogic-nar-1.9.1.6`.
I have been using `PutMarkLogic 1.9.1.6` processor to ingest documents to MarkLogic-db for more than 2 years. Recently witnessed that the processor doesn't support adding `document-quality` (PFB the processor image).
[image: PutMarkLogic 1.9.1.6]

So I have created a new issue against `marklogic/nifi` project.

Comment: I have created a fork against the `marklogic/nifi` project and added the logic to add `document-quality`. My forked branch is https://github.com/karan-prabha/nifi/tree/pk/issue-120/quality. Right now I have replaced `nifi-marklogic-nar-1.9.1.6` with the one I have built myself with the changes I have proposed in the above `issue-120`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This enhancement was fixed as part of https://github.com/marklogic/nifi/pull/121. Therefore use `nifi-marklogic-nar-1.15.3.1` or later version to set `document-quality`. I'm currently using `PutMarkLogic 1.16.3.2` and I can now see a provision to add `Quality`.
[image]

Comment: Great, thanks for the follow up - and filing the issue was the right thing to do. Please do so for any enhancement ideas you may have too!